# Using one LINQ to SQL DataContext per WCF request and automatically calling SubmitChanges?

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql

I've been scouring the web/SO for hours now so exuse me if I missed it...

I am looking for a concrete example of how to hook into the WCF pipeline when running as a WAS hosted in IIS so that a new LINQ to SQL DataContext is automatically created and disposed when the WCF request begins and ends.

Also, when the DataContext is being disposed would it be possible/ok to call `SubmitChanges()` at that point to commit any changes that have been made over the course of the request?

My main goals here are to:

- Have the DataContext lifecycle be tied to the request
- Hide the DataContext from my domain layer so that it is easily testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it would be to extend the OperationContext instance which gets created for each operation invoked in WCF. You can add extension to OperationContext. This extension can contain the DataContext instance which can be accessed and used at different location. Look at this [post](http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/)

Comment: This sounds like a good approach, I'll check it out.  Any thoughts on putting the SubmitChanges call at the point that that OperationContext gets disposed?

Comment: IExtension has DeAttach which gets called when an extension is removed from the extension list. This could be one method where you can dispose DataContext. Look at the post. Other place could be within the MessageInspector class BeforeSendReply, where the custom extension is being removed.